# Dynamic selection: need a specific column to match 4 arguments. Help using xlookup and Index function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data per date (Vector, X:1, Y:1). I have 2 sheets; sheet 1 with the source data and sheet 2 where I need the data.

---

What I need to do: I need the X-values (X:1) (I'll worry about Y-values later) from Sheet 1 (first image) to be copied over to Sheet 2 (second image) through a dynamic selection (a drop down list based on a date (which I have)). However, the X-Values have to copied in a specific order, each 'set' of data is based off of a ring, that ring is then split into 8 locations (image 3). (I hope that made sense)

---

I've tried using `=index` and `vlookup` and `xlookup` (see comments) but they don't quite work, ending up with `#REF!` and `#VALUE!` errors.

I've uploaded the current file I'm using to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kxop2SaehOeUvwl4wV3b5iVQIEIyi2VD/view?usp=sharing), if it helps please use that. Sheet 1 is sheet 1 and Sheet 2 is X+Y (Comparison (Day Selection).

Thanks

[image: Data Range in Sheet 1]
[image: Data Selection Range]
[image: 'data set']

Comment: Update 1: I have come up with this formula:
 `=XLOOKUP(1, (Sheet1!E1:ID1='X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!Q2:R2)*(Sheet1!A3:A136='X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!A4:A11)*(Sheet1!C3:C136='X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!C4:C11)*(Sheet1!E2:ID2='X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!Q3),Sheet1!HA3:ID136)`
However it comes out as `#VALUE!`

Comment: Update 2: I have another formula:
`Update 1: I have come up with 1 formula so far: =INDEX(Sheet1!E117:ID150, INDEX(MATCH('X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!Q2:R2,Sheet1!E1:ID1,0), MATCH('X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!A4,Sheet1!A3:A136,0), MATCH('X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!C4:C11,Sheet1!C3:C136,0), MATCH('X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!Q3,Sheet1!E2:ID2,)))` However, I get a `#REF!` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of How to Use XLOOKUP Across Multiple Sheets:

`=XLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$150,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$150)`

Explanation:

A1 is the search key, that is, the value that you are using for your search.

Sheet2!$A$1:$A$150 is where you expect the value of A1 to be found.

Sheet2!$B$1:$B$150 is the final output as a result of the search.

If, for example, the value in A1 is equal to the value in Sheet2 A4, the final output will be the value in Sheet2 B4.

Use relative and absolute references as necessary when copying the formula to other cells.