# xlookup across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

My current formula is: `=XLOOKUP(R2&S3,X1:EA1&X2:EA2,X1:EA150)` with the source data being in the same sheet (X1:EA150). However, the source data is not usually within the same sheet (I only copied it over to see if the formula works). How do I nest(?) another `=xlookup` within my current formula to find the source data in Sheet1. I don't really want to use helper cells as then I'll have 2 dynamic ranges unless it can be automated.

([my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74784975/17694332))

Thanks

Comment: Use sheet name before range like `Sheet2!X1:EA1&Sheet2!X2:EA2`. Show some sample and desired output.

Comment: By following this, I get this formula `=XLOOKUP('X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!R2&'X+Y Comparison (Day selection)'!R3,Sheet1!E1:DI1&Sheet1!E2:DH2,Sheet1!F3:DH150)` which then produces a #VALUE! error. Am i typing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer:

The issue doesn't concern ranges from what I can tell - it's the missing final parameter assoc. with `xlookup` (like `match`: *exact match: 0* etc.).

Of course, this assumes that your lookup ranges (`K1:N1, K2:N2`) correspond with respective lookup values that you have combined as (`H2 & I3`).

```
=XLOOKUP(H2&I3,K1:N1&K2:N2,K2:N11,"not found",0)
```

[image: xlookup]

It's a trivial matter to then cut the appropriate range (i.e. contiguous range, 1:1 correspondence with resp[. (sub/) function ranges etc)

---

But what about duplicate match results?

The above will only return the first instance of a match.  If you're looking to return every instance where there is a match, then I far prefer the filter function for this job:

```
=FILTER(K2:N11,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(K1:N1,H2,0)*MATCH(K2:N2,I3,0)))
```

And now we have this:

[image: filter]

(assumes Office 365 compatibility RE: Excel)... ta